# does pd.concat by default keep order of DataFrames in the list

Tags: python, pandas

Apologize if this has been asked/answered - can't find similar posts with Google.

I have `dfs = [df1, df2, df3, ...]` If I run `pd.concat(dfs)`, is it guaranteed that it preserves the order of `df1, df2, df3, ...`?

Comment: Yes, it's implied by the term concatination.

Comment: thank you @timgeb